# Java - Click javascript href with no id

Tags: java, htmlunit

So I have been searching around for a while and I believe I am missing something(Clearly).

I am trying to make the program to get a forum page and click on an edit button to edit the post. The problem is that the edit button is a javascript link and to be exact:

```
 <a href="javascript:EditPost(286024)">
                        Edit
                      </a>
```

This is the text area xml:

```
<textarea id="editcomment" name="editcomment" style="width:600px;
height:400px;" cols="40" rows="5" maxlength="12000" 
class="gpcommenttxtarea"></textarea>
```

And this is the post button:

```
<input type="submit" name="SaveChanges" value="" class="postbutton">
```

This is the method I wrote:

```
private static void editPost(WebClient webClient, HtmlPage page) throws IOException
{
    HtmlAnchor anchor = page.getAnchorByText("Edit");
    page = anchor.click();

    DomElement elem = page.getElementById("editcomment");

    if(elem != null)
    {
        HtmlTextArea post = (HtmlTextArea) elem;
        post.focus();
        //post.setValueAttribute("text");
        post.setText("abcefghij");

        HtmlSubmitInput postBtn = page.getElementByName("SaveChanges");
        postBtn.click();
    }

    else
        System.out.println("Failed to find");
```

The method fails to find the script element in order to click on it so my problem is probably there.

I am completely aware that my thought direction might be wrong but I taught myself everything I know about HtmlUnit(Which isn't much) so don't be too harsh.

Comment: I don't know much about the topic, but I can tell you the javascript: pseudoprotocol is a bad, bad practice from the ancient times of the internet that has no place in the modern web.

Comment: Not my website so I have no choice but HtmlUnit hates the website and I had to use
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
to avoid headache and the program crashing due to JavaScript exceptions.